# Get time taken in executing a dag on airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x

I have a problem statement ,where I need to print the time taken in completing last scheduled dag run . So for example my dag runs daily at 20:00 , I want to check how much time it took in its last run if the state was success . If it failed , just print that dag failed .

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

def print_time_taken():
    dag_run = DagRun.get_last_dagrun(dag_id='my_dag')
    if dag_run and dag_run.state == 'success':
        duration = (dag_run.end_date - dag_run.start_date).total_seconds() / 60
        print(f"The latest DAG run took {duration} minutes to complete.")
    else:
        print("The latest DAG run failed.")
```

I tried this , but it is giving me an error .

Error says DagRun has no attribute 'get_last_dagrun'.
Can someone help me in this?

Comment: *"but I am failing"* - *How* are you failing?  Does this code raise an exception?  Or return an unexpected result?  Or something else?  Please add more details to your question.  What you have looks reasonable to me.

Comment: @0x5453 I have added the error in description . It says DagRun has no attribute 'get_last_dagrun'

Comment: Perhaps you meant [`Dag.get_last_dagrun`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dag/index.html#airflow.models.dag.DAG.get_last_dagrun) or [`DagRun.get_previous_dagrun`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.5.3/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html#airflow.models.dagrun.DagRun.get_previous_dagrun)?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your requirement where you need to print the time take? Otherwise airflow UI shows how much time it takes to do each dag run so you can easily get it from UI

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/ui.html#ui-screenshots